# counting the results in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to count all the results in my table that has the same eventId in studentattendees table for every activity that I create. Here is a snippet of my two tables in my db. activity and studentattendees table.

`studentattendees` table:

[image: studentattendeestable]

`activity` table:

[image: activitytable]

I want to know how I can make a model function that counts all the results where eventId in my studentattendees is equal to activityId in activity table. Also, how I would echo this in view. Here is a sample of my code in model, view, controller.

```
//view
public function getReportAttendees(){

        $this->db->order_by('activity.activityId', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('activity');

        // date status
        $resulting = $query->result_array();
        foreach($resulting as $resultings){
        $activity = $resultings['activityId'];

        $this->db->join('activity', 'activity.activityId = 
studentattendees.eventId');
        $this->db->where('eventId',$activity);
        $this->db->from('studentattendees');
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
        foreach($count as $counts){
                array_push($countall, $count);
            }
    }

    return $countall;

}

//view

<?php 
  if($attendee){
    foreach($attendee as $attendees){
?>
    <td><?php echo $attendees; ?></td>
    <?php
    }
  }
?>

//controller 
public function ReportGenerated(){
    $data['attendee'] = $this->u->getReportAttendees();
    $this->load->view('logmanagement/reportgenerated', $data);
}
```

Comment: Try this `$this->db->get()->result()->num_row()` instead of `$count = $this->db->count_all_results();`

Comment: @DanishAli please check the answer below and see what needs to be changed.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
//modal
public function getReportAttendees(){
    $countall = array();
    $this->db->order_by('activity.activityId', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('activity');
    $resulting = $query->result_array();
    foreach($resulting as $resultings){
        $activity = $resultings['activityId'];
        $this->db->join('activity', 'activity.activityId = studentattendees.eventId');
        $this->db->where('eventId',$activity);
        $this->db->from('studentattendees');
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
        foreach($count as $counts){
            array_push($countall, $count);
        }
    }
    return $countall;

}

//view

<?php 
  if($attendee){
    foreach($attendee as $attendees){
?>
    <td><?php echo $attendees; ?></td>
    <?php
    }
  }
?>

//controller 
public function ReportGenerated(){
    $data['attendee'] = $this->u->getReportAttendees();
    $this->load->view('logmanagement/reportgenerated', $data);
}
```

Comment: please check my comments as those also my concerns. im not sure if im passing the correct variable in my foreach.

Comment: echo $count = $this->db->count_all_results();

Comment: echo  $count result is array or single variable.